# Is it the Rails way to use form helper markup?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading the guide on form helpers http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html but I'm not sure whether I actually need to write my webpages this way..

I have an HTML form like this written in `new.html.erb`

```
<form action="/posts" method="post">
  <label for="title">Test</label>
  <input id="title"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

(The `posts` page is from the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide)

When I submit the request, the server throws an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` exception.

So I changed it to

```
<%= form_for :post, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <label for="title">Test</label>
  <input id="title"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<% end %>
```

And now I have the same form, except the server now accepts the request.

Are form helpers the proper way to develop forms in Rails views?

Comment: Yes, thats what they're there for. Use them for the form tag, the inputs, the error rendering, everything. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Comment: Everyone has already mentioned how you should use it and that it has to do with CSRF. The thing is, you *won't* have the same form. Using `form_for`, if you inspect the HTML, you'll see a div underneath the declaration of the form with hidden inputs, one of which is for the `authenticity_token`, which you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes.

"Rails way" would have you rewrite this as:

```
<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "Test" %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Your attempt to use the straight HTML  tag was prevented by the CSRF protection that Rails uses on all of its non-GET requests. You must use the Rails form tags or remove CSRF protection to avoid that error.

Comment: and removing the CSRF protection is **not** recommended.