# Will I run into security issues when a mobile app requests data from a rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I've written a simple webapp using Rails and I would like to write an android app to interact with the application.

So far I only see myself making GET requests since I only need to pull data from my server and display it on the client, but if I decided that I want to make POST requests will that become a problem?

For example when I am writing the website for my rails app I need to use the form builder markup otherwise the server will reject POST requests because the authenticity token is not there.

If it is an issue, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Not 100% sure what the issue is but there are a lot of ways make posting more secure. You can generate tokens for each user session when they log in and require that authentication. You can limit what can be uploaded by checking for file types, sizes, etc in your script. I'm guessing who ever downvoted the question had an issue with your question being too broad. If there's a specific problem let us know.

Comment: It was mainly a concern that came to mind from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300064/is-it-the-rails-way-to-use-form-helper-markup as I probably won't be using rails forms when writing an android app.